# Laravel helper function link_to() does not work properly for links with non ascii characters

Tags: php, character-encoding, internationalization, laravel, laravel-4

Say for example I have in my blade file:

```
link_to('http://domain.com/foo/愛', 'You make my heart go doki doki')
```

This will actually output the anchor tag but the href will repeat the base domain i.e. `href="http://domain.com/http://domain.com/foo/愛`. I've tried with something such as `ë` which will return the same error. Do I need to apply some sort of escaping first for this to work properly or am I just not getting it?

I've dug around the code myself for `link_to` but I'm just not getting why it would repeat itself (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/872bc11f7beb11a309ec41ab2d9f6c19da18acb5/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php#L619).

EDIT: Tried doing a `urlencode()` on the url string, unfortunately same results but the slashes are now html encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omit the domain part from the `$url` parameter of the `link_to` function:

```
link_to('foo/愛', 'You make my heart go doki doki')
```

This will generate the following string:

```
<a href="http://domain.com/foo/愛">You make my heart go doki doki</a>
```

Comment: While this would work for links part of my domain, what happens when I need to link to something outside?

Comment: Good point, URL-encoding only the special character seems to work: `link_to('http://domain.com/foo/'.urlencode('愛'), 'foobar')`.

Comment: Is this a laravel thing or just me? I'm certain the battle tested framework has someone come across this before.

Comment: This is a issue of the `filter_var` PHP function used in the method `isValidUrl` of Laravel's `UrlGenerator`. `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` does not support internationalized domain names and so the domain does not pass the validation. Give it a try: `var_dump(filter_var('http://foobar.com/baz/愛', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL));`

Comment: So to summarize: this is not a Laravel issue, you will have to use `urlencode` for the path part of the URL or give up using the `link_to` helper function. Maybe think about writing your own helper function that handles this case.

Comment: I'm new to PHP and Laravel, is there any way I can extend the `link_to` functionality in a helper file without touching the framework code?

Comment: Sure: http://testandheiberg.tumblr.com/post/58147593436/custom-helper-functions-for-laravel-4